# FlowExchangeError('invalid grant') while authorising token

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am having a problem while using the `access token` retrieved using the `refresh token`. I am using `python api client` for Google doc. I have offline access mode and stored my `refresh token` in database in the userconsent part. Now using the refresh token, I am also able to retrieve the access token using requests.post. Now when I feed the access token thus retrieved to authenticate in the Flowexchange

```
self.flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET .... )
self.flow.step2_exchange(accesstoken)
```

I am getting `FlowExchangeError(u'invalid_grant',)`. Anything I m missing ?
Thanks

Comment: I can never remember which one of these gives that error.  1. check apps console under Consent screen  make sure you have filled in the product name and email address.  2. check the time on the machine you are running, Google Authentication server is picky the time has to be correct.  If that doesn't help you will need to post some code.

Comment: Sometime I think I may be messing authorization code with access token. I used the below code for retrieving and making the credential object

`accesstoken_req = requests.post( . . .)
 my_accesstoken = accesstoken_req.json()['access_token']
`

Now I am trying to use "my_accesstoken" in the flow to get the credential as
`
self.flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow( . . . )
self.__ticket = self.flow.step2_exchange(my_accesstoken)
# Here the Raises: FlowExchangeError invalid_grant
`

I m not using credential.json, just using stored refresh_token an din offline mode.

Comment: I just am a bit worried on the pattern/format of the access_token which I received on requesting a new access token using refresh token .. The request yield me something like


{u'access_token': u'ya29.KQCtO0bQO3RQ8h4AAADnnIAWjnZ_IrFQSnN1irl0t. ..... Q', u'token_type': u'Bearer', u'expires_in': 3600, u'id_token': 'big_long_string'} , normally I can see access_token has some format lke '1/4hhdjs67rufjj ..'. I dnt Know if its only my thinking. And google play get me Invalid grant too.

Comment: Since my problem is in making the flow, searching gets me DrEdit code in which the flow is created using client.json which I dont store. https://developers.google.com/drive/web/examples/python#creating_an_authorization_flow_instance. So is there any way in which I can make the flow using the access_token and refresh token. Its too hard to maintain too many client.json for many users in practically if so.

Comment: wow after a big handbang on the wall finally I proof myself winner:). Updating for all those who will/is banging head on this kind of issue. What I made the mistake is that after getting the access_token using the refresh token, we got to use the 
`credential = AccessTokenCredentials(access_token, useragent)` to create the flow and then authenticate it using the httplib. And then we can build the service using the credential object. Hope this may help some of the frens.

Comment: @phenomenon.aurora - thanks for posting it. I am surprise that its not highlighted well along with google picker, as it seems the efficient way to fetch the files once you have the access token. Please list down as answer so that it can be helpful to others.

Comment: @phenomenon.aurora - I'm trying to wrap my head around exchanging a One Time Authentication code. Apparently your comment is very helpfull, but I don't really understand it. Could you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: Was a bit late in noticing the comments... was a bit long time,  still I am just adding some of the pseudo code that I wrote at that time...  

>credobj = AccessTokenCredentials(...)  

>def my_credential()  
>    try:  
>        http = httplib2.Http()  
>        http = credobj.authorize(http)  
>    except Exception, e_:  
>        # as usual, detect the failure and take action.  
>    return http  
>http = my_credential(...)  
>service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)  

Use the service now.... Hope this may find usefull..

Comment: I tried much to format the my comment but - did not worked well, sorry for that.